# Form a loop with previous and next

Tags: java, array, linked-list, circular-list

I have a class `Edge` which looks something like this:

```
class Edge {

    Edge previous;
    Edge Next;

}
```

I have edges in an `ArrayList`. They have to form a loop, as in the last one is connected to the first one.

This is what I have:

```
    Edge previous, current, next;

    previous = edges.get(edges.size()-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < edges.size(); i++) {
        current = edges.get(i);
        next = i+1 == edges.size() ? edges.get(0) : edges.get(i+1);

        current.previousEdge = previous;
        current.nextEdge = next;

        previous = current;
    }
```

I only have the idea that this could be written clearer than it is now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a for-each iterator instead of using indexes.
It would be somewhat simpler, like this:

```
Edge previous = edges.get(nodeList.size() - 1);
for (Edge edge : edges) {
    edge.previous = previous;
    previous.next = edge;
    previous = edge;
}
```

---

Suppose the initial list of edges is not in an `ArrayList` which allows quick random access but another kind of iterable. Then, you could rewrite this way without accessing any element by index:

```
Iterator<Edge> iter = edges.iterator();

Edge first = iter.next();
Edge previous = first;
Edge edge = null;

while (iter.hasNext()) {
    edge = iter.next();
    edge.previous = previous;
    previous.next = edge;
    previous = edge;
}

if (edge != null) {
    edge.next = first;
    first.previous = edge;
}
```